# Display Records Up to a Certain Time Period Only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am organizing my dataset into 3 time intervals/shifts of 8:00am, 4:30pm, and 8:30pm as follows:

```
CASE 
WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >= '20:31' THEN '8:00' 
   WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) < '8:01' THEN 'As of 08:00' 
   WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >= '8:01' AND cast(last_update_date as 
time) < '16:31' THEN 'As of 16:30'
 WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >='16:31' and cast(last_update_date as 
time) < '20:31' THEN 'As of 20:30'
 END TimeInterval
```

The issue I am having is I don't want to show records in a time interval that has not been completed yet.

So for example, if I run my query at 8:02AM, the records that were updated at 8:01 and 8:02AM will be placed in the "as of 4:30pm" group. But 4:30pm has not "passed" yet, so these records cannot be shown in my dataset.

This also needs to be day-sensitive. For example, if I run my query at 8:02AM on Tuesday, I need to see all the records that occurred Monday, then the records to 8:00AM on Tuesday, but not after. I have already restricted my data to show only for the current week so I do not need to account for previous weeks, just the week starting Monday.

I've been able to do the second part of this by checking the day of the week of the getdate() and comparing to my update date day using the following:

```
datepart(weekday, getdate()) today_day, datepart(weekday, last_update_date) update_day
```

then in my where clause I use

```
today_day <= update_day
```

This will show today's data as well as the previous days of the week

I tried to do the same approach with the time where I get today's time:

```
cast(getdate()  as time) today_time
```

But I was unable to write case statements to change to do my comparison to the update date time. ie. I cannot do this in my case statements, or change a time stamp to a specific time stamp for example:

```
WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >= '20:31' THEN cast('8:00' as time)
```

[Below is the final output (that is put into Crytal report). In this case, the report was run on Thursday sometime in the morning, we do not want to show those circled numbers until 4:30pm has actually happened on Thursday, even if the user runs the report.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zMmi.jpg)

Below is my working query (there is a bunch of other stuff)

```
 IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Final') IS NOT NULL DROP Table #Final
SELECT getdate() today_date, cast(getdate()  as time) today_time,  
datepart(weekday, getdate()) today_day, 
DateName(weekday, last_update_date) Day_of_week_name, datepart(weekday, 
last_update_date) update_day, cast(last_update_date as time) last_update_date_Time,
CASE 
    WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >= '20:31' THEN '8:00' 
       WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) < '8:01' THEN 'As of 08:00' 
   WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >= '8:01' AND cast(last_update_date as time) 
< '16:31' THEN 'As of 16:30'
   WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >='16:31' and cast(last_update_date as time) 
< '20:31' THEN 'As of 20:30'
   END TimeInterval
   ,
   CASE 
    WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >= '20:31' THEN '08:00' 
   WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) < '8:01' THEN '08:00'
   WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >= '8:01' AND cast(last_update_date as time) 
< '16:31' THEN '16:30'
   WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >='16:31' and cast(last_update_date as time) 
< '20:31' THEN '20:30'
   END TimeInterval2
   ,

     CASE WHEN
 requisition_status_Description  = 'Pending' THEN 'Active'
 WHEN requisition_status_Description  = 'Created' THEN 'Active'
 WHEN requisition_status_Description  = 'Requested' THEN 'Active'
 WHEN requisition_status_Description  = 'Approved' THEN 'Completed'
 WHEN requisition_status_Description  = 'Denied' THEN 'Completed'
 WHEN requisition_status_Description  = 'Cancelled' THEN 'Completed'
 END RequisitionStatus
 ,
  CASE WHEN
 cast(last_update_date as time) < '16:30' then 'Regular'
 WHEN  cast(last_update_date as time) >= '16:30'  then 'Extended Hours'
 End ShiftTime, @StartWeek StartWeek, @EndWeek EndWeek
 ,*
 FROM #DataSet
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I think we need a bit more detail here to understand the question. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Off the top of my head, something like `WHEN cast(last_update_date as time) >= '8:01' AND cast(last_update_date as 
time) < '16:31' AND cast(getdate() as time) > '16:30'`?